# Highchart goes blank on certain range select

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got a Highcharts stockchart with some data loaded with range buttons enabled. It all works fine for 'all', 'week' and 'day' but chart goes blank on 'month' selector. I've tried setting max, min values for xAxis but with no luck. Am I doing something wrong here?

Sample code:

```
$(function () {
$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
    // Create the chart
    $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
        rangeSelector : {
            allButtonsEnabled: true,
            buttons: [{
                type: 'day',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Day'
            }, {
                type: 'week',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Week'
            }, {
                type: 'month',
                count: 1,
                text: 'Month'
            },{
                type: 'all',
                text: 'All'
            }],
            buttonTheme: {
                width: 60
            },
            selected: 3
        },
        title : {
            text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Custom data grouping tied to range selector'
        },
        series : [{
            name : 'AAPL',
            data : [[1439138087000,1540161],[1439224487000,1541330],[1439310887000,1542403],[1439397287000,1543351],[1439483687000,1544369],[1439570087000,1545402],[1439656487000,1546782],[1439742887000,1547984],[1439829287000,1550298],[1439915687000,1551676],[1440002087000,1552772],[1440088487000,1553908],[1440174887000,1554883],[1440261287000,1555718],[1440347687000,1556443],[1440434087000,1557156],[1440520487000,1557849],[1440606887000,1558470],[1440693287000,1560065],[1440779687000,1561005]],
            marker: {
                enabled: null, // auto
                radius: 3,
                lineWidth: 1,
                lineColor: '#FFFFFF'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 2
            }
        }]
    });
});
```

Js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/r1o1ztzu/

Comment: Showing js error in console  Invalid value for <rect> attribute x="NaN"

Comment: It's regression bug in 2.1.8, fixed already on master branch: http://jsfiddle.net/r1o1ztzu/1/ - will be included in 4.1.9 release.